# python Django - how to change a FileField to view only?

Tags: python, django

when I add a file to a FileField , I wish I could hide the option to modify the already inserted file. For example, I have a process , and the first task of the process, a person is responsible for adding a file , and the second task of this process , the person responsible for this step could only view this file, but could not modify or delete the added file in the previous step .
This is being done out of the admin interface django.

Comment: are you implying you need to use the very same form for the two steps/tasks? Otherwise use two separate forms, each focused on the fields relevant to each step

Comment: I could use two forms for each task, but the problem is that the FileField create automatic screen the option to add another file, in the second stage of the process , I just need to show the file without this option .

Comment: An "idea layout": Would it help if you used row-level [permissions](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/)? For example, after saving the model you could set it as read only. Lightweight solutions exist, like [django-rules](https://github.com/dfunckt/django-rules).Unfortunatelly I have not used this technique -yet- to provide a viable example.

Comment: http://chriskief.com/2013/09/28/django-modelform-and-conditionally-disabled-readonly-fields/  this can give you some ideas.